# How to share a common object between separate solutions while they still need same

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-core

Having trouble serializing object from one C# solution, then persisting it and picking it up with another solution, and then de-serializing directly to the same object type in a different solution.

When transferring the object to it's persisted location, it also persists it's object type with the original namespace, which is obviously different that the namespace for the shared common object that I am trying to re-de/serialize it to because they are different solutions (even though the class is the same with the same properties and same name).

Sharing classes, referencing common class, and/or linking classes doesn't seem to be the solution (unless I am doing it incorrectly), because when it picks it back up it still sees the parent namespace as different since they are from different solutions, so it gives an error when trying to de-serialize it because it thinks it is a different type.

Reason - for being able to directly de-serialize it into it's original object type but in a different project's solution.

Any insight or advice is appreciated.  Thank you

Environment:  Visual Studio 2015, .NET Core, C#  (Testing in console app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either create a class library and share it between projects or you can serialize the object to JSON and have equivalent classes on each side.

You don't mention what mechanism you are using to serialize but I am assuming it's a binary serialization you are using. If binary serialization is required a class library that is shared is your best choice.

Comment: I am utilizing Newtonsoft.JsonConvert<>() and then specifying the object type to the method, and passing the serialized string data to the method.  But since it is coming in from another solution, it has a different namespace for the original object.

Comment: JsonConvert doesn't store the namespace. The object type you are specifying, is it a type in the same solution as the deserialization?

Comment: @CodingRiot Json.Net doesn't include the namespace by default, unless you specify a value for `TypeNameHandling` in the settings - what value do you have?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am trying to use them through generics passing them into methods directliy by type - but since they are in different soultions their 'type' is seen as different
Without converting it using Newtonsoft Json solution.  I had to use the Newtonsoft Json solution to make a work around, but I would like to pass objects between solutions without having to convert them using Newtonsoft if possible

Comment: It's best to keep JSON as schema agnostic as possible. The beauty of JSON is to be able to exchange structured data between separate systems so it shouldn't specify type information. That way any system can consume the json.

Answer (score 1):

Create `Class Library`(for `.Net Core`) project. Create there classes (or interfaces or something else you want to share) you want to transfer among projects.

Then add reference to that library in every project that needs that class. Add `using` directive with library namespace and you can use these classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to share classes, or if you need another options, then you can use Serializatoin/Deserialization mechanisms that doesn't care about the original type, but rather for it compatibility with the Data. Like [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) by default.

Serialization in one solution:

```
var jsonSerializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObjectInAssemblyA);
```

Deserialization in the other solution:

```
objectInAssemblyB = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectClassName>(jsonSerializedString);
```

Comment: @CodingRiot It doesn't matter if the classes exists in different solutions/assemblies or if their names are different. What matters are the properties name, type and access modifiers. They need to be the same.
Also constructors can be an issue (if you have multiple with no default), but also this is solvable with Json.Net.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am trying to use them through generics passing them into methods directly by type - but since they are in different solutions their 'type' is seen as different Without converting it using Newtonsoft Json solution. I had to use the Newtonsoft Json solution to make a work around, but I would like to pass objects between solutions without having to convert them using Newtonsoft if possible